# npm WARN react-native-maps@0.14.0 requires a peer of react@>=15.4.0 but none was installed

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, reactjs, react-native

**Problem**

I'm trying to install react-native-maps by Airbnb in my project. Installation instructions: 
[airbnb/react-native-maps/installation](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md)

When I run the following command in cmd: `npm install react-native-maps --save`

This is what I get:
*`-- react-native-maps@0.14.0
npm WARN react-native-maps@0.14.0 requires a peer of react@>=15.4.0 but none was installed.*

Ignoring this if I proceed with further installation, and run the following command: `react-native link react-native-maps`

This is what I get:
*Scanning 561 folders for symlinks in C:\RNProjects\Mapp\node_modules (39ms)
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-maps ios dependency
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-maps has been successfully linked*

^As we can see, only iOS related maps modules get installed. On checking the project directory, I was able to validate that no android related module was installed.

**Troubleshooting**

Here's the list of thing I tried to resolve the issue, but none of them worked.

1. Tried installing `npm install react@15.4.0 --save`

Got these warnings:

*npm WARN react-native@0.43.3 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-test-renderer@16.0.0-alpha.6 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0-alpha.6 but none was installed.*

So, in order to resolve this, I tried installing react@16.0.0-alpha.6 with: `npm install react@16.0.0-alpha.6`.

I got the same message again:

*npm WARN react-native-maps@0.14.0 requires a peer of react@>=15.4.0 but none was installed.*

2. Tried updating react-native `npm update react-native`.

Still getting the same warning message.

3. Tried installing the latest version of npm: `npm install npm@latest -g`.

Didn't work.

**Additional Information**

- react-native: 0.43.3
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- Platform: Android
- Development Operating System: Windows 10 OS

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have this exact same issue on a Mac/iOS.

Comment: @JonGrant Yes, I am able to find the solution. Refer to my answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I was able to solve this (chronological order):

1. Deleted **node_module** directory from the project
2. `npm cache clean`
3. Modified package.json with: *"react":"~15.4.1"; "react-native":"0.42.3"; "react-test-renderer":"15.4.1"*
4. `npm install all module`
5. `npm install`
6. `npm i react-native-maps@0.12.5 --S`
7. `react-native link react-native-maps`

Once I do this, **it's successfully able to link the android and ios react-native-modules** to the project.

**Note:** Before running the `react-native run-android` command,

Run: `cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android`.

This will clean the gradle before running and help in avoiding any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

1. delete node_module, npm cache clean;
2. modify package.json

   "react": "~15.4.1","react-native": "0.42.3","react-test-renderer": "~15.4.1",
3. npm install all module;
4. done ;)

Comment: Can you please elaborate each step, it would be really helpful. 
Also, If possible can you explain how to downgrade the react-native-map version to 0.12.5

Thank you

Comment: You should check 'npm info react-native-maps@0.12.5' output, there is peerDependencies, you can tell what react and react-native version required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i was able to solve this same issue:

1. I deleted the node_module folder (You can verify npm cache: `npm cache verify`)
2. I actually changed the package.json file to the following:
   `"react": "~15.4.1"`,`"react-native": "0.42.3"`,`"react-test-renderer": "~15.4.1"`
   But that triggered other error on my side; So i put them back to their initial
   values:

   a. `"react": "17.0.1",`

   b. `"react-native": "0.64.0",`

   c. `"react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"`
3. `npm install all module`
4. `npm install`
5. `npm audit fix --force`
6. `npm i react-native-maps@0.12.5 --S`
7. `react-native link react-native-maps`
8. At this point I opened 2 terminals:

   a. Terminal 1: `react-native start`

   b. Terminal 2: `react-native run-android` or `yarn android`