# npm WARN react-dom@15.5.4 requires a peer of react@^15.5.4 but none was installed

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native, npm-install

I'm working on a react-native app, after installing react-native-maps i had some issues, so i deleted the project and cloned the previous version from bitbucket; when i run `npm install` the following error appear on the screen:

`npm WARN react-dom@15.5.4 requires a peer of react@^15.5.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native@0.41.2 requires a peer of react@~15.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-static-container@1.0.1 requires a peer of react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.`

and on the simulator the following screen appears:
[ERROR SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gthv7.png)

Other info:

`rereact-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.43.4
platform: IOS
Development Operating System: MacOS Sierra`

Any idea about how to solve the issue?

Comment: i tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403382/npm-warn-react-native-maps0-14-0-requires-a-peer-of-react-15-4-0-but-none-was but it didn't work

Comment: i found a solution to the problem here https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1811